# Why does include statement return an error that basically states that the language (C++) has a bug?

Tags: c++

Some info: I am a person who has gotten into C++ development recently, which means i really don't know how to troubleshoot things like this. You have been warned.

Question: *See title*

I believe I have what looks to me to be a compiler error, but have not been able to find anything like it anywhere on stack overflow.

Problematic code:

```
#include <map> // This is the line that triggered the error.

using namespace std;

class studySet
{

public:

    studySet(int t, double v, string n, string a,map<int, string[2]> s)
    {

        type = t;
        version = v;
        name = n;
        author = a;
        setTerms = s;


    }
    int getType()
    {

        return type;

    }
    double getVersion()
    {

        return version;

    }
    string getName()
    {

        return name;

    }
    string getAuthor()
    {

        return author;

    }

    void study()
    {



    }

private:

    int type;
    double version;
    string name;
    string author;
    map<int, string[2]> setTerms;


};
```

Error shown:

```
No viable overloaded '=' //Shown in a file included from above code.
```

- OS: MacOS 10.14.3 Mojave
- IDE: Xcode
- Compiler: IDK, whatever Xcode uses.

Please comment if you need more code from me as i am fairly new to stack overflow as well.

Comment: Can you show your full class? I think the problem might be in assigned `setTerms = s`.

Comment: If you are "fairly new to stackoverflow", then you should take a [tour], read the [help], learn [ask] questions, then [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements for a [mre]. Nobody will be able to help you without a [mre]. Although there are occasional compiler bugs, it's almost a certainty that you are not using C++'s templates correctly. This often results in an error reported in the header file, but the root cause is your code that does not correctly use C++'s templates. Therefore, without a [mre] nobody will be able to help you. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik When I said that I was new to stack overflow, i meant i had just recently created an account and went through all the stuff it told me to, but thanks for mentioning the minimal reproducible example part of things.

Comment: @burkejasonj Just because the error message points into a compiler/standard library internal file does not mean that there isn't a bug in your code. The error message will reference the line in your code that triggered it. Please include the *full* error message.

Comment: @walnut that was the full error message.

Comment: @burkejasonj No, that is not the full error message. You can see the full error message [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MqPe9Q). Your IDE will show you the full compiler output somewhere.

Comment: @walnut sorry about that. That was the only error message Xcode gave me. I will keep a note to check for things such as that for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` is an *allocator-aware container*. The assignment operator of such a container has the precondition that the element type, in this case `std::pair<const int, std::string[2]>`, is *CopyAssignable*.

However, `std::string[2]` is an array and array types cannot be assigned to at all.

Therefore you cannot use assignment of allocator-aware containers with `std::string[2]`. In general built-in array types don't really work in containers.

Built-in arrays often behave in very unintuitive ways. So, I suggest that you use `std::array` instead, which behaves as one would expect, i.e. instead of

```
map<int, string[2]>
```

use

```
map<int, array<string, 2>>
```

This requires `#include<array>`.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to determine that the line

```
setTerms = s;
```

triggered the error. That is because you can't pass a vector to fill another vector.

Comment: Yes you can use `=` to copy vectors. But `string[2]` is an array not a `vector`.